# Android handling clicks on parentView

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Click events handling does not work.
Click handling works with CheckBox and TextView, but doest not work with frameLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="56dp"
          android:background="@drawable/yellow_ripple"
          android:clickable="true"
         >
<TextView
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

<CheckBox
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        />
```

In create view:

```
 View resultView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.filter_signle_view, parent, true);

    selectedBox = (CheckBox) resultView.findViewById(R.id.box);
    title = (TextView) resultView.findViewById(R.id.text);

    title.setText(m_filter.getTitle());

    selectedBox.setChecked(m_state.isSelected());

    selectedBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((compoundButton, b) ->
                    m_state.setSelected(b)
    );

    resultView.setClickable(true);

    resultView.setOnClickListener(
    view -> m_state.setSelected(!m_state.isSelected())
    );
    );

    return resultView;
```

I want to handle clicks on FrameLayout. It is not happening.
(I use retrolamda)

Comment: android:focusable="false" on the views where you want the click to be passed to parent view ? tried it ?

Comment: @divyenduz it did not help

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the listener to the parent of your frame layout.
Please change last parameter of your inflation from `true` to `false`. For more - [LayoutInflater.inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,ViewGroup,boolean))

```
View resultView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.filter_signle_view, parent, false);
```

Comment: side note: that's because `inflate` returns the parent if `attachToParent` is `true`

Answer (score 0):

1) Add listener to `frame layout`. You are missing it and its the most important thing here.
2) Add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to frame layout in xml. This will prevent child items clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after fixing numerous compile errors and other Lint issues, I did run your code (slightly modified). And it worked fine, here's what I have.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:clickable="false" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And the Java part...

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View resultView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.generator_personalization, container, false);

        CheckBox selectedBox = (CheckBox) resultView.findViewById(R.id.box);
        TextView title = (TextView) resultView.findViewById(R.id.text);

        title.setText("Title!");

        selectedBox.setChecked(true);

        selectedBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Changed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        resultView.setClickable(true);
        resultView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CLICKED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return resultView;
    }
```

So basically, what I think is the biggest problem here is attaching the view to the parent in your inflate statement. Try changing that last parameter to `false`.

You should also note that setting click listeners from code also sets the `clickable` attribute when enabled.

Hope this helps!

P.S. Consider changing that layout to something more maintainable - like using a single CheckBox instead of FrameLayout + TextView + CheckBox without text.

Answer (score 0):

When you infilating a layout, you supply this parameters to the inflator service:

```
public View inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)
```

If you set attachToRoot true then the returned view is the root view that you suppilied.

In your example you set it to true and it is returning the "parent" view.

You then set a click listener to a parent viewgroup, however, the click event will be consumed on the child FrameLayout because you set the clickable to true. In your case this will do nothing because you set the click listener to the wrong view, and another view consumed the click event.

So you should set the attachToRoot to false, and the returned view will be your FrameLayout, and that will fix your problems.